# Unable to determine entity identifier for object of type "Namespace\Class"; no fields matching "id"

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, laminas-api-tools

I am trying to use ORM in my `laminas api tools`. Everything is working, however, looks like the `api-tools-hal` is not able to recognise the fields.

This is part of my `module.config.php`

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'customer.rest.customer' => [
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/customer[/:customer_id]',
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => 'Customer\\V1\\Rest\\Customer\\Controller',
                ],
            ],
        ],
],
'api-tools-hal' => [
    'metadata_map' => [
        \Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerEntity::class => [
            'entity_identifier_name' => 'id',
            'route_name' => 'customer.rest.customer',
            'route_identifier_name' => 'customer_id',
            'hydrator' => \Laminas\Hydrator\ObjectPropertyHydrator::class,
        ],
   ],
]
```

My `Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerEntity::class`

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * CustomerEntity
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={
 *   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"}),
 * })
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name = "customers")
 */
class CustomerEntity
{
    /**
     * The unique auto incremented primary key.
     *
     * @var int|null
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;
```

ORM cli command `orm:schema-tool:create` does works.

But upon going to `domain.com/customer` it throws this error:

> Unable to determine entity identifier for object of type
> "Customer\V1\Rest\CustomerType\CustomerEntity"; no fields
> matching "id"

When I remove the ORM annotation in the entity then it works.

**What do I need to do in this case?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so I need to make my fields `public`.

`protected $id;` becomes `public $id` then it works.

This is just me being stupid. Learning is good.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no, that is not stupid ;). And please, don't make your id `public` since your have no reason to do it.

Another way to fix this is to create a couple of getter/setter. In this case, I would guess that a getter is enought. So simply make a `public function getId(): ?int` to fix the error, no need for a setter as you only need it to resolve the argument of a route.

```php
public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Small tips: if you use PHPStorm, simply press Alt + Inser and then `Getter` to generate quickly this ;)

Comment: I have that and that did not help. I have `ID` and `UUID` for a table and I am querying for `UUID`, so basically `id` is always private and `uuid` is public. But I am sure there is better way of doing this.

Comment: I already have public getters and setters. Having `public function getUid()` is not helping.

Comment: I really don't know it behaves like this, but isn't it weird that it talks about `CustomerTypeEntity` when you try to fix `CustomerEntity`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, the error supposed to be this: `Unable to determine entity identifier for object of type "Customer\V1\Rest\Customer\CustomerEntity"; no fields matching "id"`. Both `CustomerEntity` and `CustomerTypeEntity` are almost identical.